# iOS Test flight application installation failed

Tags: testing, app-store-connect, testflight

I have submitted an iOS application to iTunes connect and it is in beta testing state. I have added a new external tester to the account and the new tester got the notification from iTunes connect. But the user is not able to install the application, getting an error message as below,

```
The invitation is invalid.  Try again.  If the problem persists,
```

contact the inviter.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.
I think it is some issue with iTunes. Moreover, iTunes wont allow loading apps to it from December 22 till 29th.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys,
This was an iTunes Connect error. After a couple of hours the problem got solved automatically.